# R: can I get regsubsets() to in-/exclude variables by groups?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm working with a data frame containing a lot of indicator variables that I made from categorical variables using `dummy()`. When using `regsubsets` (from the `leaps` package), is there a way to make it include these indicators by group, not individually?

In other words, can I get it to test e.g. models that contain `DF$Cat1.A`, `DF$Cat1.B`, and `DF$Cat1.C`, but not models containing `DF$Cat1.A` without `DF$Cat1.B` or `DF$Cat1.C`?

Comment: Why not combine the dummy variables in to one factor variable?